# 32 bit _asm code to 64 bit assembly code on Windows

Tags: c

i have a driver code havin an assembly code that is using `_asm` (inline assembly) its working fine when i am compiling in 32 bit WDK but it throw following error:

> "error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not
>   supported on this architecture"

please convert following `_asm` code for 64 bit compilation.

```
_asm
    {
        mov     ebx, cr0 
        push    ebx 
        and     ebx, ~010000h 
        mov     cr0, ebx
    }
```

Comment: Visual C++ does not support inline assembly for x64 compilations.

Comment: Where does it say he is using visual c++ ?

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık The "`error C4235`" implies it. Neither ICC nor GCC uses that error numbering systems.

Comment: will it support 64 bit in the future?

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık Ask Microsoft. My guess is never - as is C99 for their C compiler.

Comment: Microsoft has decided that you must either use [intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds.aspx) in C or [assemble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb5z4sxd.aspx) a separate object.  No mixing of C and inline assembly anymore.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık The error code is formatted as a typical VC++ error, the `_asm` keyword is a VC++ extension, and the assembler code is in Intel format, all pointing to VC++.

Comment: Visual C++'s inline assembly syntax sucks and everyone knows it. But MS will not adopt GCC's (superior) syntax because it wasn't made by MS. So that's probably the end of it. The user base for inline assembly is probably too small for them to care anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Using Microsoft's compiler intrinsics,

```
#include <intrin.h>
__writecr0(__readcr0() & ~0x1000);
```

This should work on both x86 and x64 (though of course manipulating `CR0` can only be done in kernel mode).

Comment: As a side note, unsetting WP sounds like a pretty awful hack.